# Lightbox Rails Asset Pipeline misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, image, asset-pipeline, lightbox2

I'm unsure as to why my close and loading images aren't loading when lightbox is called on my rails app. I've correctly copied over the files and and the js and css is working fine but I'm getting broken images for close and loading.

Here is `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require justgage
//= require raphael.min
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
//= require lightbox
//= require_tree .
```

My `application.css`

```
 *
 *= require jquery.ui.datepicker
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= bootstrap
 *= lightbox
 */
```

And in my images folder I have `close.png` and `loading.gif`

Here is the output from the request

```
Started GET "/images/close.png" for IP at 2013-01-01 12:39:19 -0800
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/close.png"):
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /Users/tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

And a similar error is shown for the `loading.gif`

Do I need to change something in my routes file? What am I overlooking here? If I correctly included the js and css shouldn't the images be included appropriately as well? Thanks for your attention and for taking a look.

------UPDATE-------

update application.css

```
 *= require jquery.ui.datepicker
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require lightbox
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

same broken images still appear.

Comment: Do I need to add .erb extensions to the lightbox files and add an 'image_tag' to closing and loading to correctly reference the images?

Comment: The proper way is to change all calls like `../img/image.png` to `image/image.png` . Adding `.erb` will help if you referencing it like `<% asset_path %>/image.png` , but `image_tag` is used in views , not in `.css` files.

Comment: Does it work when you place all the lightbox's files in the public/ folder and leave them as they are when downloaded (and writing the calls in the <head></head> like you would in a simple html project) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this :

```
*= require_tree .
*= bootstrap
*= lightbox
*/
```

If it is really in your `application.css` , it should be :

```
*= require bootstrap
*= require lightbox
*= require_tree .
*/
```

EDIT : You can take a look at the `lightbox.css` file and check how are the images referenced . Then you should chose how to change it - hard-coded , like `images/image.png` with normal `.css` file prefix , or by `<% asset_path %>/image.png` and `.css.erb` .

Comment: The css (opacity, borders, positioning, etc.) is correctly rendered it is just the lightbox images (loading, close) appearing as broken when clicking lightbox links.

Comment: You can take a look at the `lightbox.css` file and check how are the images referenced . Then you should chose how to change it - hard-coded , like `images/image.png` with normal `.css` file prefix , or by `<% asset_path %>/image.png` and `.css.erb` .

Comment: yes, there was my confusion it is referenced in the js file. I've chosen to hard code the paths thanks for your attention.